# createorupdate function is not working. fill model missing Argument

Tags: php, laravel

Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::fill() must be of the type array, null given,

```
public function createOrUpdate(Staff $staff, Request $request)
{
    $staff->fill($request->get('staff'))->save();
   
    $staff->attachment()->syncWithoutDetaching(
        $request->input('staff.attachment', [])
    );

    Alert::info('You have successfully Added a Member.');

    return redirect()->route('platform.staff');
}
```

Comment: error is obvious  `$request->get('staff')` gives only single value missing the column name use `$request->all()` for the array or provide custom array

Answer (score 0):

Provide an associative  array of `key => value` in your fill() method

```
public function createOrUpdate(Staff $staff, Request $request)
{
    $staff->fill(['column_name' => $request->get('staff')])->save();
   
    $staff->attachment()->syncWithoutDetaching(
        $request->input('staff.attachment', [])
    );

    Alert::info('You have successfully Added a Member.');

    return redirect()->route('platform.staff');
}
```

Note :  make sure you have a `protected $fillable` property

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment